# Can't receive return value from callback function in another function [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, callback

I am trying to get a return value from a function, but all I get is 'undefined'. I would guess its due to the order in which JS executes the functions, but first let me present a shortened version of the code:

```
// Analyzing Jenkins log
function analyseRawLog(callback) {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            callback(this.responseText);
        } else if (this.readyState === 4) {
            console.log("Failed to get raw console output.");
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", "consoleText", true);
    xhttp.send();
}


// Takes as a parameter the output ofthe console, which
// is parsed from previous function
function analyseMetricsLog(consoleOutput) {
    let analysisArray = [];

    console.log("Analysing logs...");

    // A for loop regexing the console output
    // Results are appended in the array, which I return in the end


    return analysisArray
}

// initiating the function on the page
analyseRawLog(analyseMetricsLog)
```

So far, it works as intended (because I use console.log for each information I parse). However, I want to add an extra UI in Jenkins page, which contains this information. This is why I added this `analysisArray`, which contains all information. I plan to add this array in another function, which visualises the information in the Jenkins UI. This is a simplified version of what I tried to do:

```
function analyzeUI(){
// skipping the unimportant UI stuff
let results = []; // creating an array to contain the results

results = analyzeRawLog(analyzeMetricsLog) // I want to get the return value of 
                                           // the function, so I output it in 
                                              the UI
}
```

However, if I try to `console.log(results)`, I will get undefined, which I guess it's due to the function executing after this. I tried a couple of solutions, but none of them seem to work:

1) Making a nested callback:

`function analyseMetricsLog(consoleOutput, callback)`

And in the end of the .js file:

`analyseUI(analyseRawLog(AnalyzeMetricsLog))`

I tried to get the callback value in my UI function, but
it says that callback is not a function.

2) I tried using `async` and `await`, which I have never used before, but
the result was the exact same.

Could you please give me any tips how to get this return value?

Comment: When `analyzeMetricsLog` returns its value, it's returning it to `analyzeRawLog`, which isn't doing anything with it. Instead, use a callback within `analyzeUI`: `function analyzeUI(){
    analyzeRawLog(function(rawResults) {
        const results = analyzeMetricsLog(rawResults);
        /* ...use results here... */
    });
}` See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much!!! I was losing my mind.